# New and Unknown Netstat Entries

Tags: linux, debian, redis, netstat

OS = Debian 10.

When I run `netstat -natp`, I have two unidentified entries which are concerning.

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6379          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      24310/redis-server  


tcp6       0      0 :::4949                 :::*                    LISTEN      1556/perl
```

I keep the system updated weekly and do not remember seeing or installing `redis-server`. Also, I cannot find a program outside of `munin` associated with perl on port 4949. Any help or advice is appreciated.

Comment: What exactly do you want help or advice with? You seem to have correctly identified the running programs.

Comment: Do you have any idea why `redis-server` would just show up in the netstat entries? Also, should I be concerned about perl listening on port 4949?

Comment: Because someone installed it, and because it's a Debian system, Debian autostarted it. I have no idea whether you should be concerned about what appears to be munin-node.

Comment: Took at look at `/var/log/apt/history.log` and found `redis-server` tied as a dependency to `ntopng` which was installed recently. I attempted to purge the program, but I guess it was left behind. Still searching for `munin`. It may not seem like it, but your questioning has helped.  `sudo apt purge redis*` removed the `netstat` entry.

Comment: Consider the possibility that it might be something else? Check its command line, e.g. with `ps 1506`.

Comment: `1556 ?        Ss     1:04 /usr/bin/perl -wT /usr/sbin/munin-node`  look to be a munin-node

Answer (score 0):

Took at look at `/var/log/apt/history.log` and found `redis-server` tied as a dependency to `ntopng` which was installed recently. I attempted to purge the program, but I guess it was left behind. `sudo apt purge redis*` removed the `netstat` entry.

After running `sudo ps 1556` (as suggested by Michael Hampton above), the perl program seems to be a `munin-node`. It seems the `munin` node is a dependency tied to the `virt-goodies` package used for virtualbox. It seems to only be listening to local traffic and is needed for vituralbox to run properly, so I will be leaving it.